# Restore files in a git reset --hard HEAD repository

Tags: git

This is the situation:

```
git init
git remote add origin ..
git add *.*
git commit -m 'Init'
git add -all
```

And trying to revert 'Init' commit

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

and redo commit

```
git commit -m 'Init'
```

result:

```
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

And directories lost :(

NEED TO RESTORE SOURCE FILES

Tried this:

```
 git reset HEAD@{0}
```

Help please

Comment: Show me output of "git reflog"

Comment: 26bef1b HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): Init

Comment: Do you see your files after running "git checkout 26bef1b" ?

Comment: Note: checking out '26bef1b'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 26bef1b... Initial commit

Comment: Yep. Do you see for files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85508/discussion-between-willem-and-david8).

Comment: Please try "git show 26bef1b"

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I use `git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable HEAD` for locating the files, in this case I need all of them.

And with `git show 'each_line_of_gitfsck' > file` save each file.

Don't have the path of each one, but have a backup with the structure.

So much Thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2465760/david8) to help me to solve this.